# creating new folder hangs current window on pc?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-2, usb-mass-storage

As all of you might know the galaxy note 2 (n7100) doesn't provide the usb mass storage option when connecting to pc.

It connects to the pc as a media storage or camera storage option. Upon clicking on it, I am able to access my card and internal memory.

But when I try to create new folder in the card or internal memory, the current working window freezes.

Also reading writing everything works just fine. And I can create the new folder on windows desktop and then copy to card or internal memory it works just fine. But not able to create folder directly in the card or internal memory, as every time working window hangs and I need to re connect the phone to pc.

Comment: It sounds like you've found a bug in Windows, and you've cleverly come up with a workaround for that bug. What's your Android question?

Comment: @DanHulme But if there is a way to get usb mass storage working, Then this can be resolved. So how to enable usb mass storage for note 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having a similar problem. Just wait for a minute or so and that folder does get created eventually. Of course the workaround is to either:

1. Create Folder on a local Windows Drive and then copy it onto the phone
   OR
2. Install Custom Recovery and reboot into it and activate USB Mass Storage